# Why can my local website (not hosted) load icons from external css links without internet?

Tags: fonts, html, css

I'm doing a website and testing some icons from some google external css link. I wrote the external link into the index.html file and everything worked fine. Then I got the idea to test what would happen if I don't have internet. I expected the icons to not be loaded. They loaded fine, even though I don't have access to internet. Why did that happen? How is that possible?

Comment: Force a full refresh of the page (usually Shift + F5).  Do they still load?

Comment: check browser cache

Comment: For more background on the cache, check out this page: https://refreshyourcache.com/en/cache/

Answer (score 1):

This is due to your browser caching the files.  Caching temporarily saves the data you view to your hard drive.  This includes the text and images on web pages, and therefore the icons in question.

What is the purpose of caching data?  Speed.  By downloading the files locally, you dont have to download the data repeatedly as you navigate the website, or go back to it at a later date/time.  In some cases, the time saved is insignificant, but in others, you can visibly see pages load instantly, as you already have the data.

As people mentioned in the comments, if you clear your browser's cache, the icons will disappear.  However, if you open a different browser and test it, the icons wont appear, as they were never cached by that browser.

On a side note, some browsers will even cache data for pages you havent even looked at yet.  This is called pre-fetching.  While you are looking at a web page the browser will navigate the links in the background and start downloading those pages into its cache, just so they will load faster in case you do click those links.